# Using Attributes or Settings Class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Customer class that contains an Address field. From what I have researched, I can either use attributes:

```
public class Customer{
   //...
   [Required]
   public Address CustomerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

or another way:

```
public class AddressSettings{
   public bool AddressRequired { get; set; }
   //...other settings
}
```

Are both ways a valid approach? If not, why is the other way better?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion using attributes are better and more professional, using attributes are more readable, more flexible, easier to manage and they have lots of out of the box features

Answer (score 1):

For basic validation, you are better off with DataAnnotations.

Another option is [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation/) (which I highly recommend)

You can have a separate class for validation, but still have strongly-typed associations with your viewmodel properties

```
[Validator(typeof(PersonValidator))]
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person> {
    public PersonValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(0, 10);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(x => x.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60);
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can have much more complex and rich validation logic.

Comment: I also recommend fluent validation, this prevents attribute-soup in large projects.